# The camera plugin is freezing or entering an infinite loop when taking a picture in an emulator with Android 12 installed

Tags: flutter, dart

The latest version of the camera plugin as from writing this issue is 0.10.5+2 and the emulator being used is a Pixel 6 with Android 12 installed.

When trying to take a picture with the method `takePicture()` from the `CameraController` something is freezing inside or entering an infinite loop, where none of the lines that comes next are being executed. The worst part is that no exception is being thrown.

Consider the following example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final cameraController = CameraController(
    (await availableCameras())[0],
    ResolutionPreset.max,
  );

  await cameraController.initialize();

  final app = MaterialApp(
    home: CameraScreen(
      controller: cameraController,
    ),
  );

  runApp(app);
}

class CameraScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final CameraController controller;

  Future<void> takePicture() async {
    await controller.takePicture(); // This call never returns a future.
    print('A picture was captured.'); // Therefore, this line is never executed.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(controller),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: takePicture,
              child: const Text('TAKE PICTURE'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In this example, the print statement is never executed because `takePicture()` remains stuck in an infinite loop or something.

An updated version of the previous example using a `StatefulWidget` instead.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final app = MaterialApp(
    home: CameraScreen(
      description: (await availableCameras())[0],
    ),
  );

  runApp(app);
}

class CameraScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CameraScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.description,
  });

  final CameraDescription description;

  @override
  State<CameraScreen> createState() => _CameraScreenState();
}

class _CameraScreenState extends State<CameraScreen> {
  late CameraController controller;

  Future<void> takePicture() async {
    await controller.takePicture(); // This call never returns a future.
    print('A picture was captured.'); // Therefore, this line is never executed.
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = CameraController(
      widget.description,
      ResolutionPreset.max,
    );

    if (controller.value.isInitialized == false) {
      controller.initialize();
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CameraPreview(controller),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: takePicture,
              child: const Text('TAKE PICTURE'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: show us your full code from initState method to this, where-ever you use `controller`

Comment: @Nguyenfamily the issue was updated to include the block of code you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a `StatefulWidget` instead of a `StatelessWidget`?

Usually, a controller is created in the `initState` method of a `State` object and exclusively used by this state or its descendants.
When the widget is done, Flutter calls the `dispose` method, which allows you to dispose your `CameraController` to prevent memory leaks.

Here is an example of such a widget and its state using the `CameraController`:
https://pub.dev/packages/camera#example

TLDR:
Transform your widget to a `StatefulWidget` and move the controller creation in its `initState` and don't forget to call `controller.dispose()` in your `State.dispose` method.

EDIT:
There seems to be an open bug report for this package: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/126125

> I can see the issue on Pixel 2 Android 12.0 (emulator) whilst it works on physical device Pixel 3a, Android 12 as mentioned at #126125 (comment). Both front and rear cameras also don't work.

Maybe try a physical device instead of an emulator?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but it didn't solve the problem. An updated version of this issue now includes an exmaple using a StatefulWidget instead.

Comment: I awarded 50 points of reputation to this answer by mistake. Clearly the problem is not solved.

Comment: @XUNIT I added the link to a bug report that seems to involve the same problem you are experiencing.

Comment: I already tried on a physical device and everything is fine. However, this issue focuses on emulators only.

Comment: Then I guess you already have your answer, it is a known bug in the library. You can either open a pull request to fix it yourself or upvote the issue, so it gets more priority.

Comment: Fine, I guess those 50 points awarded are no longer by mistake.